# Local storage value is undefined on router change event in angular

Tags: angular

**top-navigation.component.ts**

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.tokenDecoded = this.jwtDecoderService.getDecodedAccessToken();
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
        if (this.platformId === 'browser') {
            if (this.tokenDecoded.id !== undefined && (Date.now() < (this.tokenDecoded.exp * 1000))) {
                this.loginDataService.sendData(true);
            } else {
                localStorage.removeItem('token');
                this.loginDataService.sendData(false);
            }
        }
      
    });

}
```

**decoded token service**

```
..     
public getDecodedAccessToken() {
            const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            try {
                return jwt_decode(token);
            } catch (Error) {
                return {};
            }
        }
..
```

On route change this.tokenDecoded value remains undefined and send false data to loginDataService which further display the element as logged out. However on refresh  this.tokenDecoded is captured correct of token is available and send true to the loginDataService.

How to make sure  this.tokenDecoded is captured right without page refresh

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz? It would help

Comment: can you try adding to `this.router.events` a pipe `this.router.events.pipe(filter(ev => ev instanceof NavigationEnd)` (or something of the like). Maybe your event is triggering on navigationStart or something and well.. platformId won't be what you expect it to be then?

Comment: or simply console.log your platformId and see if it breaks on navigation

Comment: If I refresh the page everything else works fine as expected ,even route change read the value correct then, so after first successful google login it needs a refresh which I want to avoid.
The code just check if the button should display login or show profile on each navigation and if invalid it just ask for login.

Comment: Instead of calling the service jwtDecode when I use localStorage.getItem('token') directly it works fine.